# Single word for the thing substituted

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a noun that means the thing substituted.

> These substitutions are not perfect. There are material differences between the substitutes and ______________.

Comment: "...the originals"?

Comment: "...the replacements"?

Comment: the substituted.

Comment: @Rob_Ster No; that's 'substitutes' again.

Comment: The *substituted*.

Comment: Should it depend on what  is being substituted,  in case of an employee you sub for the regular or the permanent one. While improvising in manufacturing  you can substitute a component for the part specified/

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mark Hubbard's comment. How about **originals**?

OD:

> [**original**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/original):
>   Present or existing from the beginning; first or earliest.

Your example:

> These substitutions are not perfect. There are material differences
>   between the substitutes and **the originals**.

Comment: It conflicts with my sense of what's right when someone submits an answer largely echoing a previous comment, which was given as a comment rather than an answer presumably because the commenter considered it not to be too exact an answer. 'An original' and 'a thing that has been replaced by a substitute' overlap to a limited extent. You might have an original and a copy, for instance, in the same set.

Comment: Others have transformed comments they think are of 'answer' standard to community wikis rather than submitting them as their own answers. Don't you find that more gracious?

Answer (score 1):

> These substitutions are not perfect. There are material differences
>   between the substitutes and the ***substituted***.

Here, *the **substituted*** stands (as a noun) for *the things which were substituted*. It is the past participle of *substitute* and hence functions as an adjective (as per the ODO definition of [*past participle*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/past_participle)), which in turn is allowed to act as a noun (in this context).
Check the reference below, specifically, the example where *the **insured*** (past participle of *[insure](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insure)*) is used in the sense of *those who are insured* (noun).

M-W Learner's Dictionary - "Ask the Editor":

> **[Adjectives used as nouns](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/adjectives-used-as-nouns)**
>
> Can adjectives function like nouns?
>   **Answer**: Just as nouns can function
>   like adjectives, <strike>as we highlighted in our previous post,</strike> so can
>   adjectives function like nouns.
>
> A lot of adjectives are used this way, many referring to classes of
>   people:
>   a shelter for the homeless
>   tax breaks for *the **insured***

Answer (score -1):

**Ersatz** as in ersatz coffee made from acorns that the British drank during the rationing and privations of World War 1939-45.

"Borrowed from German, where *Ersatz* is a noun meaning 'substitute,' the word was frequently applied...in English to items like coffee (from acorns) and flour (from potatoes) - ersatz products resulting from privations of war." (Merriam-Webster).

Comment: He's asking for a word for the thing that was there prior to the substitute, not a word for the substitute. Also, *ersatz* generally implies that the replacement is not as good as the original.