# A word for the item which is being substituted

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an item which is being substituted? I would call the replacement item the "substitute", but I cannot find a name for the item being replaced.

In my case I'm programatically searching through a list of words, looking for words to replace with other words. I need a good variable name for the term to replace, and "term_to_replace" is unsatisfying!

I imagine the same word could also be applied to a rugby player who is being called off the pitch to be replaced by another.

Comment: In the sporting context I am familiar with *subbed off* for the player leaving the ground, and *subbed on* for the replacement player. However these are not what you are looking for.

Comment: What is it about `term_to_replace` that unsatisfies you? It seems perfectly piacevole to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "original", or just "the substituted" used as a noun?

There's a similar English Language & Usage Stack Exchange post from a few years back that offers a few variations [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369222/single-word-for-the-thing-substituted). The original poster linked to [this source](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/adjectives-used-as-nouns) at the Britannica Dictionary about using adjectives as nouns.

Depending on the formality of the context, "substitutee" certainly follows grammatical conventions of the "-ee" suffix usage and is perfectly understandable, even if it's not found in a standard dictionary. [Here](https://doi.org/10.4000/anglophonia.3504)'s a 2020 article on the -ee suffix usage and wider acceptance.

Comment: Thank you! "The Substituted" or "Substitutee" make sense. I was thinking too big!

Comment: No. The OP wants a word for "the item being replaced". Not the substituted item, but rather the replaced item in whose place it was substituted.

Comment: Yes, it's a confusing set of words, but "the substituted" is in contrast to "the substitute" - using "the substituted" as a noun rather than an adjective changes the understanding (see link in original answer). In contrast, other variants of "the item doing the replacing" might be the substituting word vs the substitute - these read the same to me

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is **substituendum:** Something to be substituted or replaced.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substituendum

Comment: Said nobody ever.

Comment: And yet, when I saw the question I knew what to search for... It's the same Latin construction as with "addend" and "subtrahend". (Also infrequently used, at least until we get elementary school teachers to start introducing the children to `sed -e 's/.../.../g'` )

Comment: Yeah, but it's used only in a very narrow technical sense and is not something ordinary people would understand.

Comment: Yes. And @op says they're looking for the right variable name for their program. It's nerds, all the way down.

Comment: Except .... wrong kind of nerds.